# Maya Python static class function scope

Tags: maya

I have some trouble getting my static class to work. There is something I am missing about the scope of functions within a class. If called the script gives me following error:

```
     NameError: global name 'disableCostumFrames' is not defined #



import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial

class Blast:
    def createWindow():
        # Todo:
        #    hanldes the gui for the user

        windowID = 'window'

        if cmds.window(windowID, exists = True):
            cmds.deleteUI('window')

        window = cmds.window(windowID, title="Blast", iconName='Blast', widthHeight=(400, 200) )
        cmds.frameLayout( label='')

        cmds.rowColumnLayout( numberOfColumns=4, columnWidth=[(1, 100),(3, 100)] )
        cmds.text( label='Start: ' )
        global Blast_startFrame
        Blast_startFrame = cmds.textField( enable = False)
        cmds.text( label=' End: ' )
        global Blast_endFrame
        Blast_endFrame = cmds.textField( enable = False)
        cmds.setParent('..')

        cmds.rowColumnLayout( numberOfColumns=2, columnWidth=[(1, 100), (2, 100)] )
        cmds.radioCollection()
        #cmds.radioButton( label='Full', select = True, onCommand= partial(disableCostumFrames, Blast_startFrame, Blast_endFrame ) )
        #cmds.radioButton( label='Costum', onCommand= partial(enableCostumFrames, Blast_startFrame, Blast_endFrame ) )
        cmds.setParent('..')

        cmds.rowColumnLayout( numberOfColumns=1, columnWidth=[(1, 400), (2, 100)] )   
        cmds.button( label='Playblast' ,command= 'createPlayblast')
        cmds.setParent('..')

        cmds.showWindow( window )

        return Blast_startFrame, Blast_endFrame

    def main():
        createWindow()

    def enableCostumFrames(Blast_startFrame, Blast_endFrame, *args):
        cmds.textField(Blast_startFrame, edit=True, enable=True)
        cmds.textField(Blast_endFrame, edit=True, enable=True)


    def disableCostumFrames(Blast_startFrame, Blast_endFrame, *args):
        cmds.textField(Blast_startFrame, edit=True, text="", enable=False)
        cmds.textField(Blast_endFrame, edit=True, text="", enable=False)
```

How do I need to define these functions within the class?  I am calling the module like that:

```
import sys
Dir = 'c:/Blast'
if Dir not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(Dir)
try: reload(Blast_v011)
except: import Blast_v011

Blast_v011.Blast()
```

maybe iam doing something wrong on this side? Appreciated any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you need to add a `self` reference to all of the methods in your class.  The usual python class looks like this:

```
class MyClass(object):

   def __init__(self):
       self.variable = 123

   def some_method(self):
       print "my variable = ", self.variable

   def some_other_method(self):
       if self.variable > 1:
          self.some_method()
```

The `self` reference in the member functions is how you get at class member variables and other functions -- it's python's way of referring to what other languages call `this`.

Instance methods can only be called on an instance (it's the instance that gets passed in as `self`).  You can make a method that is called on the class itself -- rather than any particular instance of the class -- using the `@classmethod` decorator.  Classmethods also take an argument, but instead of `self` it's a reference to the class. You use it the same way to get variables defined at the class level, which are shared by all copies of the class:

```
class HasShared(object):
    shared = 99

    @classmethod
    def a_class_method(cls):
        print cls.shared
```

(You can mix and match class and instance methods in the same class).

You can also make static methods using the `@staticmethod` decorator.  These don't get a default argument at all:

```
 class NotPythonic(object):

     @staticmethod
     def needs_no_args():
         print "call me as NotPythonic.needs_no_args()"
```

In Python we tend to avoid this formula, since you can get a static method by just creating a function in a module without making a class to hold them. For the example code you posted, I'd probably just make a conventional class using instance methods, since your functions need the names of the gui widgets to be able to actually ask them questions.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I encounterd another problem when I call my lets say my creatWindow function within my class. I understand that I need to call the function like: self.createWindow. But it gives me the error "# NameError: name 'self' is not defined #".

Comment: You need to add an argument to all member functions.  Calling it `self` is a convention only, but there has to be something there

Comment: alright I am getting closer to fixing it. My problem stays with my "disableCostumFrames" functions. These using partial from functions and are called like:         cmds.radioButton( label='Full', select = True, onCommand= partial(disableCostumFrames, Blast_startFrame, Blast_endFrame ) ). How do I go for using them with self?

Comment: You'd have to create the partials from the methods:  `onCommand = partial(self.disableCostumeFrames, startframe, endframe)`